# How to insert a string in another string after a specific string pattern

Tags: perl

I have string in Perl:

```
X 682.9 X 683.9 X 1.0
```

I want to insert `0.3 0.3` after `682.9`. Required output is:

```
X 682.9 0.3 0.3 X 683.9 X 1.0
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Matt Jacob* has already given the right answer. This is a way incase you don't know the length of substring, you can use `index` and `length` function:

```
my $str = "X 682.9 X 683.9 X 1.0";
my $i = index($str, "682.9") + length "682.9";
substr($str, $i, 0) = " 0.3 0.3";
print $str, "\n";
```

Output:

```
X 682.9 0.3 0.3 X 683.9 X 1.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot it helped, as i was not knowing the length of string . :-)

Comment: @rohan: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
my $str = 'X 682.9 X 683.9 X 1.0';
substr($str, 8, 0) = '0.3 0.3 ';
print "$str\n";
```

If you really wanted to use a regular expression for some reason, I suppose you could do it this way:

```
$str =~ s/682\.9 /682.9 0.3 0.3 /;
```

Output:

```
X 682.9 0.3 0.3 X 683.9 X 1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this
RegEx substitution enough for this

```
my $string ="X 682.9 X 683.9 X 1.0";
$string =~s/(682\.9)/$1 0.3 0.3/;
print $string;
```

Comment: No need for `/g` or the capturing groups, and you probably want to escape the `.`: `$string =~ s/682\.9 /682.9 0.3 0.3 /;`

Comment: @MattJacob Thank you for your usefull comment. I edited